# Firebase Functions: ReferenceError: decodedToken is not defined

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

```
ReferenceError: decodedToken is not defined
    at admin.auth.verifyIdToken.then.catch (/user_code/index.js:88:181)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:64:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

Hello, i'm getting the following error where decodedToken appears to be undefined and this was working recently but in the past day or so the error has begun and is preventing me from verify tokens.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

module.exports = function(req, res) {
    // Return status status 422 with status message.
    if (!(req.body.idToken && req.body.projectDocId)) {
        return res.status(422).send({ status: "bad_input", message: "The request does not contain the correct and required params." });
    }

    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.body.idToken).then((decodedToken) => {
        let uid = decodedToken.uid;
        admin.auth().getUser(uid).then((user) => {
            if (user) {
                admin.firestore().collection("projects").doc(req.body.projectDocId).collection("data").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What version of the functions are you using? They did some breaking changes in a (somewhat) recent update, so that might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll be honest...

It turns out that on my side app side I was authenticating with another project of mine, and not the correct one which also reflects on why the authentication wasn't working.

A prompt of copying code across from my other projects and updating / changing where neccessary :D